# How to access JSON within API response?

Tags: ruby, arrays, json, api

I am making an API call that returns the following response:

```
{
    "firstName": "",
    "lastName": "",
    "address": {
        "type": "",
        "address1": "",
        "address2": "",
        "city": "",
        "state": "",
        "zipCode": "",
        "country": ""
    },
    "race": "",
    "phones": [
        {
            "type": "",
            "number": ""
        }
    ],
    "joinDate": ""
}
```

How can I access the `"number"` variable within the `"phones"` array? I tried this:

```
@phone = response["phones"].map { |s| s["number"] }

puts phone
```

but I had no luck. I am using Ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: Because `phones` is an array, you stand a good chance of having multiple "number" keys in the sub-hashes. Which one do you want? All of them? The first? A specific one? It's important to state that in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@phone = response["phones"].map { |s| s["number"] }
puts @phone # puts the instance var @phone, not unassigned local var phone
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a hash inside an array. This returns the first number:

```
@phone = response["phones"][0]["number"]
```

Or if you want all numbers as an array:

```
@numbers = response["phones"].map { |phones| phones["number"] }

@phone = @numbers.first
```

Comment: +1. These handle the situation nicely if there are multiple "phones" defined in the array.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - The error I was receiving was because of how I was calling the variable, but this method of defining the variable works better.

Answer (score 0):

With `select` for hash:

```
phone = response["phones"].select { |f| f["number"] }
puts phone
```